# php make link from mysql results

Tags: php, mysql, echo

How can i make the $row['Fname'] to be a link and when i click it, redirect me to a new page with more info about this entry i clicked?

here is the code:

```
echo '<ol>'; 
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)){

echo '<li>';
echo '<img src="'.$row['Bio']. '" alt="" width="110" height="110">';
echo '  <dl>';
echo '  <dt>Name</dt>';
echo '  <dd>'.$row['Fname'].'</dd>';
echo '  <dt>Genre</dt>';
echo '  <dd>'.$row['Genre'].'</dd>';
echo '  <dt>Speciality</dt>';
echo '  <dd>'.$row['Specialty'].'</dd>';
echo ' </dl>';
echo '</li>';

}
echo '</ol>';
```

Comment: just wrap it using `<dd><a href=pageyouwant.php?fname="'.$row['Fname'].'">'.$row['Fname'].'</a></dd>` and then in the pageyouwant.php just grab that variable using `$_GET['fname']`

Comment: Thank you very much! and in the new page will i be able also to display the genre and specialty and some more columns that the specific name have?

Comment: I posted as an answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just wrap it using

```
<dd><a href=pageyouwant.php?fname="'.$row['Fname'].'">'.$row['Fname'].'</a></dd>
```

and then in the pageyouwant.php just grab that variable using `$_GET['fname']`

pageyouwant.php

```
$fname = $_GET['fname'];

$sql = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE fname LIKE '%$fname%'";
```

Using this in php, you can get all the info regarding the fname :)

And then you're all set :)

Comment: Thank you! But what is it going to echo?

Comment: I might have a problem. The entries in Mysql database have utf8 encoding and where i have space it stops the link. For  example here is the results page `/Search_Results.php` and whe i click the name to redirect me when it's in Greek, it shows like this: `/profile.php?Fname="Χρήστος` while the link should be: `/profile.php?Fname="Χρήστος Καραπετσάκος"` Any ideas about this?

Comment: Probably you'll need to use [htmlentities()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php)
Just like: `href=pageyouwant.php?fname="'.htmlentities($row['fname']).'">`

Comment: Yeah it works but it gives me symbols in the link. how to set the characters to utf-8 for the htmlentities?

Answer (score 0):

Use this line:

```
echo '  <dd><a href="'.$row['id'].'">'.$row['Fname'].'</a></dd>';
```